# How can I disable TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 cipher in Apache2?

Tags: ssl, apache-2.4, apache2, encryption, cipher

In [SSL labs](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/), I got that I'm using this "weak cipher":

```
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
```

Now in Apache, this is the set of suites I have enabled:

```
SSLCipherSuite ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384
```

To that list above, I tried adding `!ECDHE-RSA-AES256-CBC-SHA384`, but that didn't help. I also tried adding `!CBC`, and that doesn't fix the problem in SSL Labs either. What should I do to disable this cipher?

I'm on Debian Buster. The Apache version I'm using is `2.4.38-3+deb10u3`. Everything is up-to-date.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The cipher suite you are trying to remove is called `ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384` by *openssl*.

Whenever in your list of ciphers appears `AES256` **not** followed by `GCM`, it means the server will use AES in [Cipher Block Chaining](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation#Cipher_Block_Chaining_(CBC)) mode. This cipher is by no means broken or weak (especially when used with a good hash function like the SHA-2 variants you have in your list). It is just less recommended than Galois Counter Mode.

Before manually choosing your ciphers your should read [Mozilla's Server Side TLS page](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Security/Server_Side_TLS) to make an aware choice. E.g. Debian 8 is just 4 years old and it doesn't have **openssl** version 1.1.

Once you edit your list of cipher suites as you like, you can test the result with:

```
openssl ciphers -v 'ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384'
```

Comment: Thank you. That works! I think they don't prefer CBC cipher mode because it doesn't have authentication, so it might cause problems. I, personally, don't use any encryption without authentication anymore.